# difference between ssh ProxyCommand and running that command directly (cloudflared)

Tags: ssh, cloudflare

I have a remote machine I can access only through a `cloudflared` tunnel.  In my `.ssh/config` file I have

```
Host remote
     User my-user-name
     ProxyCommand cloudflared access ssh --hostname remote-host-name.com
```

this works fine.  When I `ssh remote` I get a prompt on `remote-host-name.com`.

But when I just run the `cloudflared` command directly I get an error:

```
local$ cloudflared access ssh --hostname remote-host-name.com
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5

Invalid SSH identification string.
```

I thought `ssh` was just "exec"ing the ProxyCommand, but it must be doing something more, what else is it doing?

Comment: Weirdly, CF mentions here https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/ssh-service-token/ that running `cloudflared access ssh --hostname remote-host-name.com` directly. Yet the same documentation links to here https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/gitlab/#configuring-ssh mentioning that you have to set your ssh config to use the `ProxyCommand`. However, even when I modified the SSH config, I could only use `ssh`, and running `cloudflared` still didn't work. So did you figure out how to run `cloudflared` directly? Or still via  `ssh` with `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: it turns out that `cloudflared access ssh --hostname remote-host-name.com` actually just sets up a tcp tunnel (like a vpn) and has nothing directly to do with `ssh` despite the `ssh` as one of the command line elements.  So the only way to get this working is to put the ProxyCommand in the ~/.ssh/config file or:
`ssh -o "ProxyCommand='cloudflared access ssh --hostname %h'" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProxyCommand` specifies the command to use **to connect to the server** (from the manual page, emphasis mine). Basically it runs this command and uses its input/output streams instead of directly opening a tcp connection. On top of that, it is running the `ssh` protocol.

In other words, `ProxyCommand` only replaces the tcp stream, but the rest of the `ssh` communication is still being run natively by the actual `ssh` command. When you run the `cloudflared` command by itself, you are just connecting to the ssh server from the other side and receive the `ssh` greeting (`SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5`) and the other side expects you to answer with whatever the protocol specifies (which of course a human is not expected to do, that is what `ssh` is doing in the background).
You will get a similar greeting by trying to connect directly with `nc` to any `ssh` server without proxies, e.g. `nc some.ssh.server 22` (22 is the port commonly used by `ssh`).